# Reconstituting assignment statement strings into objects

Tags: python, algorithm, api, parsing

As it is hard to articulate what I am trying to do an example is probably the best thing to show. This is the output I have from an API

```
a[0].b[0].d.e=0
a[0].b[0].d.f='1,2'
a[0].b[0].d.h='x,y'
a[0].b[0].d.i=1
a[0].b[0].d.g[0]='X'
a[0].b[0].d.g[1]='Y'
a[0].b[0].d.j='D1,CIF'
a[0].c[0].d.e=0
a[0].c[0].d.f='1,2'
a[0].c[0].d.h='H,M'
a[0].c[0].d.i=2
a[0].c[0].d.g[0]='M'
a[0].c[0].d.g[1]='H'
...
```

I want to get this output into an object such that I have a single object 'a' and I can query accordingly as an object which contains objects, arrays, etc.

Comment: what is the format of the output above, string or json string or ?

Comment: It is a string; as you can see they are a bunch of assignment statements.